# Using variable in jenkins file for robocopy command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, robocopy

I am writing a Jenkins pipeline script to copy files from the source to the destination folder. The only difference from lots of articles I already visited is that my source and destination paths are not fixed but constructed using variables. I have a very strange issue that the variable names are used instead of their value, have been trying since the whole day. My Jenkins script is below

```
pipeline 
{
    agent any
    
    parameters
    { 
        string(name: 'SPRINT_NUMBER', defaultValue: '', description: 'Sprint Number')
    }
    
    environment 
    {
      DESTINATION_PATH=""
      SOURCE_PATH=""
    }
       
    stages 
    {
        stage('Copy') 
        {
            steps 
            {
                script 
                {
                   
                     /* APPROACH-1*/
                    DESTINATION_PATH="C:\\Release\\" + "${env.SPRINT_NUMBER}" + "\\" + "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}" +"\\Destination"
                    SOURCE_PATH="C:\\Source\\bin"
                    echo  "DESTINATION_PATH: ${DESTINATION_PATH}"
                    echo  "DESTINATION_PATH: ${SOURCE_PATH}"
                    /* the below doesnt work, echo prints correct DESTINATION_PATH and SOURCE_PATH though*/
                    bat '(robocopy ${SOURCE_PATH} ${DESTINATION_PATH}) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 exit 0)'
                   
                    /* APPROACH-2*/
                    bat label: '', script: '''Set src="C:\\Source\\bin"
                    Set dest="C:\\Release\\${params.SPRINT_NUMBER}\\${BUILD_NUMBER}\\Destination"
                    /* the below doesnt work, the variable name used instead of values*/
                    robocopy %src% %dest%'''

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Console out put from Jenkins is
**For first approach**

```
7:00:58  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:00:58     ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
17:00:58  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:00:58  
17:00:58    Started : Tuesday, July 28, 2020 5:00:58 PM
17:00:58     Source : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CopyFilesJob\${SOURCE_PATH}\
17:00:58       Dest : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CopyFilesJob\${DESTINATION_PATH}\
17:00:58  
17:00:58      Files : .
17:00:58        
17:00:58    Options : . /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

**For second approach**

```
17:00:58  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:00:58     ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
17:00:58  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:00:58  
17:00:58    Started : Tuesday, July 28, 2020 5:00:58 PM
17:00:58     Source : C:\Source\bin\
17:00:58       Dest : C:\Release\${params.SPRINT_NUMBER}\${BUILD_NUMBER}\Destination\
17:00:58  
17:00:58      Files : .
17:00:58        
17:00:58    Options : . /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

Comment: The variables SPRINT_NUMBER, BUILD_NUMBER in the second approach, or the SOURCE_PATH and DESTINATION_PATH in the first approach are used as it is instead of their values. How to get their values is the challenge for me here

Comment: In APPROACH-2, instead of ${params.SPRINT_NUMBER} I also tried using ${env.SPRINT_NUMBER} too but also doesn't work